# What for using KEY-LISTVAL in item trigger?

Tags: oracle12c, oracleforms

I had been working on oracle form 6i for long time and now convert to 12c.

I used not to create item trigger KEY-LISTVAL to handle LOV pop up because the LOV works perfectly as long as the LOV attached to a correct item.

However, some programmers likes to create KEY-LISTVAL to each items which has LOV attached.  In the item trigger writes:

```
list_values;
```

LOV seems work no different even without this code.  Why using this trigger?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use it most of the time to create an if statement in the trigger.
If the item is empty select the value with an lov (list_values).
If the item is not empty open another form with the details of the value you selected.

Answer (score 0):

If the KEY-LISTVAL trigger has its "Fire in Enter-Query Mode" property set to "No", this could allow an LOV to be used in data entry mode, but not in query mode.